# Calculating correlation between residuals of linear regression with NAs and independent variable in R

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to calculate the correlation coefficient between the residuals of a linear regression and the independent variable `p`.

Basically, the linear regression estimates the current sales as a function of the current price `p` and the past price `p1`.
The vector of current prices `mydf$p` has length 8, but the residuals is a vector of length 7 because one entry has been deleted due to the `NA` value of `p1`.

```
# lag vector and pad with NAs
# Source: http://heuristically.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/lag-function-for-data-frames/
lagpad <- function(x, k) {
  if (!is.vector(x)) 
    stop('x must be a vector')
  if (!is.numeric(x)) 
    stop('x must be numeric')
  if (!is.numeric(k))
    stop('k must be numeric')
  if (1 != length(k))
    stop('k must be a single number')
  c(rep(NA, k), x)[1 : length(x)] 
}

mydf <- data.frame(p = c(10, 8, 10, 9, 10, 9, 10, 8))
mydf$p1 <- lagpad(mydf$p,1)
mydf$sales <- with(mydf, 200 - 15 * p + 5 * p1) + rnorm(nrow(mydf), 0,0.13)

model <- lm(data = mydf, formula = 'sales ~ p + p1')

print(summary(model))

print(cor(residuals(model), mydf$p))
# Error in cor(residuals(model), mydf$p) : incompatible dimensions
```

In this particular case, it is easy to use `mydf$p[2:8]` instead of `mydf$p`.
However, in general, there may be multiple rows at random locations where then NAs are deleted.
How do I access the independent variables that were actually used in the regression after removing the rows containing NA?

One of my attempts was based on the [R documentation for lm](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/lm.html). I tried to access the "x" matrix through `model[['x']]` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the actual data used to fit the model from `model$model`, and from there the `p` column:

```
cor(residuals(model), model$model$p)
```

---

Alternatively, `is.na(mydf$p1)` will tell you which rows in `mydf` have an `NA` in column `p1`:

```
cor(residuals(model), mydf$p[!is.na(mydf$p1)])
```

In general, `is.na(x)` tells us whether elements in `x` are `NA` or not:

```
> is.na(c(1,2,NA,4,NA,6))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

The x matrix is only created if you specify x=T in your call to lm. Then model$x will give you the value of x (this is more idiomatic that model[['x']].

lm handles missing values by just completely omitting an observation where a value is missing. Maybe you want to do something like:

```
cor(residuals(model), mydf$p[!is.na(mydf$p)])
```

?

Answer (score 1):

model.matrix(model) seems to be what you are looking for
Then you can select the variables you want with [] and the column number or name